# Need help overriding compareTo

Tags: sorting, interface, comparable, compareto

I'm a Java novice that is having some trouble overriding the compareTo method in the Comparable interface. My code creates a HashMap that associates strings to an int. I would like to override compareTo so that the strings in the ArrayList keys are sorted based on their HashMap values, not alphabetically. Under this implementation, however, the strings are still sorted alphabetically.

Oh, and to clarify, nameWeight is the HashMap of String,Integer pairs.

Any ideas?

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(nameWeight.keySet());
System.out.println(keys);
Collections.sort(keys);


public int compareTo(String that){
    int gtr = 1;
    int less = -1;
    int eql = 0;
    System.out.print(this);
    System.out.print(that);
    if(that=="JOHN")
        return less;
    int valThis = nameWeight.get(this);
    int valThat = nameWeight.get(that);
    if(valThis==valThat)
        return eql;
    if(valThis>valThat)
        return gtr;
    if(valThis<valThat)
        return less;
    return gtr;


}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum hashCode() is not used with an ArrayList.

Comment: Since the desire is to sort a list of Strings, you'll need to pass a Comparator to use [Collections.sort with a Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)). Alternatively, create a new Collection of *your custom Comparable type* that uses composition and sort that.

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting a list of strings so the `compareTo` method called is the one defined in class `String` (or its superclass). Since you can't modify `String` you would have to create a subclass of String, override `compareTo` in that class and use `List<StringSubClass>`. But since `String` is `final` you're not allowed to subclass from it (thanks @pst).

Alternatively you don't use `String` objects in the list but objects of the type you created and in which you override `compareTo` (don't forget to add `implements Comparable` to the class definition).

Or (shameless plug from @pst again), and that is probably the best solution, you pass a comparator to the `sort` function which will be used to sort the strings instead of the default implementation.

Comment: [String is final](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) - either composition or an external Comparator will need to be used.

Comment: Yes, I know. I never suggested changing `String`(?)

Comment: I see. No subclasses... Thanks for the hint :) updated my answer.